# Document Library Issue: All users are unable to upload files

Tags: document-library, permissions, error

In my document library only users with Full Control group can upload files or edit them, no other user permission levels are working. There are no workflows attached to this library.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What permissions do these users have? It sounds as if there might be an issue with the permissions role the users have. Look in the Permission Levels option in the Settings screen in the Advanced Permissions link of Central administration to verify the permission being used for the affected users grants them the ability to add and edit items.

Is there content approval turned on in this document library?

Comment: No, Content Approval is turned off.

Comment: Can you please give out a solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you using any customized permission levels on the site that may be applied to this document library that would prevent users from adding or editing items?  It sounds like the users have been applied a Read type permission and therefore not able to add or edit files.

Comment: DocLib has unique permissions with different permission levels. 'Read-Only' is mostly untouched.

Comment: If users have read only permission, they cannot add or edit anything.  You have to make sure the permissions role assigned to the users that are to add and edit items has those permissions available to them.  Look in the Permission Levels option in the Settings screen in the Advanced Permissions link of Central administration.